# Tolist is not emitting in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I trying to filter the list after taking the input from edittext ,Actually its filtering the list but i want to group the result to list.

So I used to list operator with SingleObserver but result is not coming; why is this?

```html
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchEdit)
                .skip(1)
                .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .switchMap(new Function<TextViewTextChangeEvent, Observable<List<VehicleMakeModel>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<List<VehicleMakeModel>> apply(TextViewTextChangeEvent textViewTextChangeEvent) throws Exception {
                        return Observable.just(variantlist);
                    }
                })
                .flatMapIterable(new Function<List<VehicleMakeModel>, List<VehicleMakeModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<VehicleMakeModel> apply(List<VehicleMakeModel> v) {
                        return v;
                    }
                })
                .filter(new Predicate<VehicleMakeModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(VehicleMakeModel v) {
                        if (searchEdit.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                            return true;
                        else
                            return v.getVariant().toLowerCase().trim().contains(searchEdit.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim());

                    }
                })
                .map(new Function<VehicleMakeModel, VehicleMakeModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public VehicleMakeModel apply(VehicleMakeModel integer) throws Exception {
                        return integer;

                    }
                })
                .toList()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<VehicleMakeModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<VehicleMakeModel> vehicleMakeModels) {
                        System.out.println("testing");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: fix your code block please

Comment: You should put in an error handler as well because if an error is occurring you won't know about it.

Comment: Even error is not coming i checked up.

Comment: Does `RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchEdit)` ever complete? If it doesn't, then `toList()` will never complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is a must-remember fact about RxBinding: event observables never complete.

`RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchEdit)` will never call the complete callback, so `toList()` won't never return your expected list.

This is not a bug, but a wanted behavior for RxBinding because your textChanges observable will never stop listening for that event.